# Polyfill-es5 is it required for Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills

[image]

After project built I have output with two polyfill files. Both are required? What is the difference between polyfill-es5.js and polyfill.js

Comment: Sorry, I am not voting up anything that has images for textual information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular always includes the `polyfills-es5.js` file if your build target is ES5, which makes your Angular app compatible with browsers as old as IE11 (at least an empty app).

If your own code makes uses of ES6+ features that are not included in Angular's polyfills, you have to add them in the dedicated `polyfills.ts` file of your project which will output the `polyfill.js` file